# How do I use, in a linker script, an object file in an archive?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

I'm using `arm-none-eabi-ld` for linking, though I don't believe the ARM aspect of the problem changes anything. I could be wrong.

I have a `test-crt0.o` object file in an archive called `libtest.a`

In my linker script I have:

```
STARTUP(test-crt0.o)
```

But I get this error:

> $ arm-none-eabi-ld build/main.o -T script.ld -ltest
>
> arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find test-crt0.o

Is there any way to point it specifically to the object file that is in the lib I'm linking to?

EDIT: I've used this in another linker script that worked fine:

```
 .text : {
   *test-crt0.o (.text)
   *(.text)
 }
```

The asterisk was needed in that case, but evidently doesn't work with STARTUP.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this, i have posted my problem which is similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/65092280/3924689

Answer (score 0):

You still need to pass `test-crt0.o` filename to `ld` on the command-line.

The entry in the linker script simply tells it where to go.

Comment: So how do I pass it? Like I said, it's in an archive file.